# How do I prevent users from Saving word document as another file

Tags: vba, ms-word

Making a field mandatory before saving Microsoft Word document.

```
Public Sub FileSave()
    Dim orng As Word.Range
    Dim ofld As FormFields

    Set orng = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set ofld = orng.FormFields

    For i = 1 To ofld.Count
        ofld(i).Select
        If ofld(i).Result = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please ensure that all are filled."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```

This code only prevents saving the document without filling the form. It does not prevent  users from saving the document in another format. How do I modify it so that users are also unable to save as another document?

To provide some context, previously i had another code at the module level that prevented users from saving the document as another format. Issue is it also prevents users from saving the document at all. I'm trying to find a solution that will prevent users from saving as another name and/or format and only allowing them to save the document after filling in all the mandatory fields. If users deactivate macros the document is essentially useless to them, so that's not a concern. My query relates to after a user enables macros and accesses the document

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveasUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("You are not allowed to save this file as another document")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't, the user will always be able to save it in another format, he just needs to deactivate macros. There is no way to block this securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to test for `If SaveAsUI Then` and only cancel if the `SaveAsUI` is `True`:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("You are not allowed to save this file as another document")
    End If
End Sub
```

But note that this is not secure at all and can easily be tricked out.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, however i've run into a couple of issues. When i put this code at the module level it highlights "WithEvents" and a pop up says "Only valid in object module". When i put it in the object module it highlights "WithEvents App As Word. Application" and a popup says Invalid attribute in Sub or Function. Really appreciate your help as i am a complete novice.

Comment: @ldm89 you need to put it into `ThisDocument` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks very much! it works now. I shifted the first code over to modules and the above one to ThisDocument.